# .htaccess only pick first number in id

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have done some research to know how to use the `.htaccess` file but i'm now facing an issue I know have a solution.

i have a url like this `http://localhost/mycup/check/?download=4`
and i use this below rewrite rule which works fine.

```
RewriteRule ^check/([0-9]) check/?download=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now, the issue is, the rewrite rule work for `download=1` to `download=9`. If download changes to `download=10`, 11, 12...19 it will only return `download=1`.

If download changes to download=21, 21...29, it will return only the first digit which is 2. if it is 9824, it will return 9. Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you literally wanted that with the `([0-9])` pattern. If you need more digits you should write i.e. `([0-9]+)` instead.

In general read about [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) prior writing rewrite rules.